# Update Observable collection from different UI

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a WPF application which shows a Folder's contents in a Treeview in the MainWindowView. Now I have a new window where the user can change the location and press reload. Now I want to update the treeview in my MainWindowView as soon as the user presses the Reload button.

I am using an ObservableCollection object which is binded to the treeview. But I am not able to update the collection from the Change location window.

I want to know how to update the ObservableCollection of the MainWindowView from a different window. If I am doing any changes in the MainWindowView, then it immediately reflects in the TreeView

I am using MVVM architecture.

Comment: You expect us to be able to help without explaining what 'not able to' means in this context and without showing any code at all?

Comment: @PeterBons This is my question. I want to know how to update the ObservableCollection of the MainWindowView from a different window. If I am doing any changes in the MainWindowView, then it immediately reflects in the TreeView.

Comment: You can build a FolderService and pass it to both ViewModels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any relationship between the `MainWindow` and the `ChangeLocationWindow`?
How does the `ChangeLocationWindow` show out, `Show()` or `ShowDialog()`? Check the following solution, any problems, let me know.

`MainWindowViewModel`:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public  static MainWindowViewModel Instance = new MainWindowViewModel();

    public ObservableCollection<string> Contents = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public string Location
    {
        get { return _location; }
        set
        {
            if (_location != value)
            {
                _location = value;
                ReloadContents();
            }
        }
    }

    private MainWindowViewModel()
    {
    }

    private void ReloadContents()
    {
        // fill test data
        Contents.Add("Some test data.");
    }

    private string _location;
}
```

`MainWindowView`:

```
{
    public MainWindowView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyListBox.ItemsSource = MainWindowViewModel.Instance.Contents;

        var changeLocationWindow = new ChangeLocationWindow();
        changeLocationWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

`ChangeLocationWindow`:

```
public partial class ChangeLocationWindow : Window
{
    public ChangeLocationWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindowViewModel.Instance.Location = "Test";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Iron . This was really helpful. It worked for me out of the box..

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to your problem is using Messaging pattern to send notifications to main viewmodel from another one about new changes.

Checkout the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more details,